# Custom Dialog that looks like a AlertDialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog, attr

i'm currently creating a custom dialog (alertdialog is not flexible enough for my needs). and i want it to look like a AlertDialog, with that well kown AlertDialog header (see image below).

also i got a listview within my custom dialog and i want it to look like a listview of the AlertDialog. how could i do that?

so far i found alertDialogTheme and alertDialogStyle in the attr. class, but i don't know how to use it.

what it should look like using a custom dialog:
[image: typical alertdialog with listview]

what it looks like (black background, wrong header): [image: custom]

my layouts are pretty basic and look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_root"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

the listview contains items that use this layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_noimage" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

any ideas?

---> workaround using alerdialog with custom view, but now i got the following problem with some gaps:

[image: gapsproblem]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a normal `AlertDialog` using the typical `AlertDialog` title/header but then set the content of the dialog to use a custom view:

```
// Your custom layout can be whatever you want
View customLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customLayout, null);

// Create the dialog box
AlertDialog myDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
  .setTitle("My Title")
  .setView(customLayout)
  .create();

// Show the dialog box
myDialog.show();
```

This will result in a normal looking `AlertDialog` with the normal looking title, but the content will use whatever custom view you want.

For the ListView you want to display as the content, you are simply going to need to recreate the View as you see fit and use it as the `customLayout` in my example.

Comment: hmm well the header should work. but the list i'm providing is created dynamicly. i'm not sure what you mean by recreate the listviews items. could you more precicely explain how to get the look of the alertdialog listview for my custom listview i would provide as the customLayout?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no default theme you can inherit or anything like that. You just need to manually lay out the items and set their margins and padding and the font sizes to make it match what you want. FYI, you can dynamically alter the items in the list for the `AlertDialog` before you create the `AlertDialog`. Why doesn't that work for you?

Comment: well it works as you suggested now, except for one small error i still got, i edited the inital question with a example image of the problem: i cant get a rid of those gaps!